# Where can I find a list of properties for 'item' in plothover function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plot, flot

So I have this function:

```
 $.fn.UseTooltip = function () {
        $(this).bind("plothover", function (event, pos, item) {
            if (item) {
             ......

                item.pageX, item.pageY, item.series.data, item.dataIndex...
```

I was wondering where there is a list of all of item's properties. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe: `console.dir(item)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There isn't a complete list of properties in the documentation. But you can get the properties by inspecting the `item` object in the developer tools of your browser (either by setting a breakpoint or outputting the item in the console with `console.log(item);`).

The result is something like this (depending on plugins used and the options of your plot):

```
{
   [functions]: ... ,
   dataIndex: 3,
   datapoint: [
      0: 2006,
      1: 5907,
      2: 0,
      length: 3
   ],
   pageX: 635,
   pageY: 504,
   series: {
      [functions]: ... ,
      bars: { ... },
      color: "rgb(237,194,64)",
      dashes: { ... },
      data: [ ... ],
      datapoints: { ... },
      label: "Plot1",
      lines: { ... },
      points: { ... },
      shadowSize: 0,
      stack: true,
      xaxis: { ... },
      yaxis: { ... }
   },
   seriesIndex: 0
}
```

Comment: I was wanting to see everything available to item to use. Will this list that or just what I have set in options already?

Comment: This shows what you  have set and what flot has automatically set.

Comment: awesome! That's probly the best I can get right now.